# Kafka issue in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

When any message push to Kafka topic i'm seeing below message.
my message contains only 5 elements and it is plain text only it wont exceed 300 characters still seeing below error.

```
WARN [SocketServer brokerId=0] Unexpected error from /127.0.0.1; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1920298859 larger than 504857600)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:381)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:342)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:609)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:541)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:467)
        at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:689)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:594)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If no active consumer for long time around 8 to 10 hours kafka itself killing in Kubernetes.

I want some good article to setup Kafka cluster in Kubernetes any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`1920298859` is a recognizable value, it's `ruok` decoded as a integer:

```
>>> struct.unpack("!I", struct.pack("!4s", "ruok".encode("UTF8")))
(1920298859,)
```

It looks like you have some Zookeeper tooling/healthcheck trying to connect to Kafka. The `ruok` command should only be sent to Zookeeper hosts. Kafka only accepts connections from Kafka clients.

Comment: Thanks Mickael, can you provide some insight about the kafka in kube environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "some insight"? In your post, there was actually no question! I guessed you were asking about the exception you pasted.